# How can I implement the function erase of a list of stack?

Tags: c++, list, stack

I have a list that has stack with int and it is order low to high, by the top of stack. I need to implement the function erase, with a value given in the function. The head of the function would be:

```
void Delete(list<stack<int> > &L, int element)
```

[image: An example about the function do]

In the left it is before call the function, and in the right is how would be the list after to call the function.

Also, the list must be ordered by the top of stack after the execution of the function.

How could I do it in C++?

Thank so much!

Comment: Do you want to remove, from each stack, an element with the value passed by `element`, if present? Also, *the list must be ordered by the top of stack* -- what does this mean? Why is the stack {1,0} the first stack in the resulting list?

Comment: If you see the first image, it is the list of stacks at the first. When you do the function (you pass int 2 like element), you remove it of all of stacks in the list that it has number 2.
The stack {0,1} is the first because you after the function, order the stacks by the number in the top of them, low to high number in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two operations you'd like to implement.

- iterate over stacks and if `top == element`, erase it.
- sort the list

Iterating through the list will look simillar to this

```
for (auto iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
{
    // element exists and is equal to required input
    // same as !iter->empty()
    if (iter->size() && iter->top() == element)
        iter->pop();

    // deleted last element
    // same as iter->empty()
    if (!iter->size())
        iter = list.erase(iter);
}
```

And sort is as easy with `list::sort`

```
list.sort([](const std::stack<int>& left, const std::stack<int>& right) {
    return left.top() < right.top();
});
```

---

**Edit** regarding your question in the comment.
Calling `list.sort()` will attempt to sort elements of the list (`std::stack<int>` in your code) using `operator<`. `std::stack` however does not implement such operator for comparisms, thus you have to implement your own function telling the sort method "which elements is smaller than the other" (In your case `std::stack<int> left, right`, `left` is smaller than `right` if `left.top() < right.top()`, therefore, comparing first elements of the stack). There are many ways how to provide sort method such function, I used anonymous lambda expression.

Comment: Thank so much for your help! Only one question, when you are doing
    (iter->size())        and       (!iter-size())
 what are you checking?

Comment: `iter->size()` checks whether stack contains one or more elements. `!iter->size()` checks if the stack is empty.

Comment: Only one question more, if I put `list.sort()` it would must to do the same that your function?